# How to use mysql subquery with a where clause in a where clause that requires data from the superquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause

i'm going to try this:

```
SELECT
    Bestellung.ID BNr,
    RechnAddr Kunde,
    (SELECT
        Name
     FROM `User`
     WHERE ID = Bestellung.SalesPerson) Verkaeufer,
    Clerk Sachbearbeiter,
    (SELECT
         Ort
     FROM `Location`
     WHERE ID = Bestellung.Location) Standort,
    CONCAT_WS('.', LPAD(Day, 2,'0'), LPAD(Month, 2,'0'), Year) Erstelldatum 
FROM `Bestellung`
WHERE
    SalesPerson != ''
AND
    (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM _BestellungsPosition bp
     WHERE bp.OrderID = Bestellung.BNr) = 0
```

i just want all orders that have no order items, but mysql tells me "Unknown column 'Bestellung.BNr' in 'where clause"...
am i using the subquery wrong?!

please help me

---

edit: i changed the (pseudo) query i used before to the true one, because my pseudo query worked, but the true one with real data didn't

---

edit2: now i changed the query to:

```
SELECT
    Bestellung.ID BNr,
    RechnAddr Kunde,
    (SELECT
        Name
     FROM `User`
     WHERE ID = Bestellung.SalesPerson) Verkaeufer,
    Clerk Sachbearbeiter,
    (SELECT
         Ort
     FROM `Location`
     WHERE ID = Bestellung.Location) Standort,
    CONCAT_WS('.', LPAD(Day, 2,'0'), LPAD(Month, 2,'0'), Year) Erstelldatum 
FROM `Bestellung` LEFT JOIN _BestellungsPosition bp
WHERE
    SalesPerson != ''
AND
    bp.Order IS NULL
```

and it works... thanks to the responder with this hint, but he deleted his answer i think

Comment: It seems like you'd really want a join predicate rather than a Cartesian product, e.g.: `LEFT JOIN _BestellungsPosition bp ON bp.OrderID = Bestellung.BNr `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit2: now i changed the query to:

```
SELECT
    Bestellung.ID BNr,
    RechnAddr Kunde,
    (SELECT
        Name
     FROM `User`
     WHERE ID = Bestellung.SalesPerson) Verkaeufer,
    Clerk Sachbearbeiter,
    (SELECT
         Ort
     FROM `Location`
     WHERE ID = Bestellung.Location) Standort,
    CONCAT_WS('.', LPAD(Day, 2,'0'), LPAD(Month, 2,'0'), Year) Erstelldatum 
FROM `Bestellung` LEFT JOIN _BestellungsPosition bp
WHERE
    SalesPerson != ''
AND
    bp.Order IS NULL
```

and it works... thanks to the responder with this hint, but he deleted his answer i think

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the IDs to select (or exclude) in a subquery and it may be inefficient. Try this below:

```
SELECT
    ID, Customer, SalesPerson, Clerk, Date
FROM `Order`
WHERE ID NOT IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT OrderID FROM OrderItem);
```

Comment: NM... Blaise did a more efficient query.